# CSS animation two padding animations

Tags: css

Is it possible to do 2 padding values ​​in a transition

```
export const logoHeader = css`
  background: #1572E8 !important;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  max-width:240px !important;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  transition: width .300s;
`
```

I have this div that has a padding-left by default of 24
and then I have a state true or false where true have this css by default and false I call an additional css to modify my padding:

```
  export const logoHeaderClosed = css`
  padding: 0 px
  transition: padding .3s;
  `;
```

where my padding becomes 0, but after that I would need my padding back to 24

i.e. the padding would have to change twice in this transition I don't know if this is possible with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with simple CSS animations. Just set the `animation-fill-mode` to forwards so it stops after the animation completes and keeps the padding at 24px.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("div").toggleClass("on");
})
```

```css
div
{
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

div.on
{
  animation: pad 0.3s linear;
}

@keyframes pad
{
  0%
  {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  
  100%
  {
    padding-left: 24px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>a div</div>
<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro !!!! i can use 50% or others % for more animation?